# pg_restore into PG 13: error: could not execute query: ERROR: must be owner of index

Tags: pg-restore

I'm running this `pg_restore` (13.5) command:

```bash
pg_restore -d <connection_uri> \
  --single-transaction \
  --clean \
  --if-exists \
  --no-owner \
  --role=www \
  --schema my_schema \
  --verbose \
  my_schema.sql
```

it always went well (for years!) on a former PG 9.6.24 target database on a Unix system.

But when I'd like to restore it in a PG 13.5 database (also Unix based), everything went fine until I face this error on indexes:

```bash
(...)
pg_restore: from TOC entry 137621; 1259 98127301 INDEX index_street_geom_182716 grp-admin
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: must be owner of index index_street_geom_182716
```

Here on the first line, `grp-admin` is the username of the owner of that schema in the source database.

The source DB from which the dump of the schema comes from is 9.5.1 on a Windows server.
The dump was made using `pg_dump` (13.5):

```bash
pg_dump -d <connection_uri> \
  --format custom \
  --no-privileges \
  --schema my_schema \
  --file my_schema.sql
```

Is there anything I can do to properly restore this schema in the new 13.5 database?

I have already double checked the rights of the role `www` using `select * from pg_shadow where usename like 'www';` on both target databases (9.6.1 and 13.5) and results are exactly the same (it's not a superuser though).

The `www` role is needed on the target database to be used by a web application.